# Simple equation solving with two variables

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This is my first post here, so bear with me. Also, my first language isn't English, but I hope that won't be a problem.

So my question is probably a piece of cake, but since I'm a youngster and haven't studied that far yet, I can figure this out.

If I have the equation $x^2 - a = 5$, with what value of a is the equation equal to $-2$?

Comment: What do you mean by an equation being equal to -2? Do you mean the root of the equation?

Comment: You would be well off if you learned some formatting. Which can be found [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Also you generally need to show your work when asking a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this answer your question?

$$x^2 - a =5$$
$$x^2=5+a$$
$$x=\pm \sqrt{5+a}$$
So $$\pm \sqrt{5+a} = -2$$
When we square both sides we can remove the $(\pm)$ sign
$$5+a=4$$
$$a=4-5$$
$$a=-1$$